# Deallocation of items in QStandardItemModel

Tags: c++, memory-management, qt5, qlist, qstandarditem

When `QStandardItemModel`, which is allocated on the stack, gets destroyed, what happens with objects to which pointers in the model are pointing at (e.g. `item`/`item2` pointer as in the following example):

```
QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem("test");
QStandardItem* item2 = new QStandardItem("test2");

QList<QStandardItem*> list;
list.append(item);
list.append(item2);

QStandardItemModel model;
model.addRow(list);
```

In this context, if i understood correctly, row in a model is consisted of N values, each value in that row represented as `QStandardItem`. This means that "list" object above is one row with two values (columns).

Is this better or worse than using `model.setData()`, `model.setRowCount()` and manually tracking coordinates?

If full context is needed, it's [here](https://github.com/mispp/goat/blob/fwdonly/ui/QueryTab.cpp). Idea is to manually loop over `QSqlQuery` results and fetch rows in chunks. Relevant method is called `loadChunk`.

If the model is stack allocated, do i need to somehow manage deallocation of items loaded to model via `addRow()`

TLDR; how to make sure that model doesn't leak memory when model is stack allocated, but contains a lot of pointers to objects on heap?

Comment: Use C++ smart pointer to wrap  `QStandardItem` -:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: It is `QStandardItemModel::appendRow`, not `QStandardItemModel::addRow`.

Now to the topic:

You do not need to worry about manually destroying *QStandardItem* objects. When the model they belong to is destroyed, so are they.

To demonstrate that inherit from *QStandardItem* and put a debug message in the destructor like this:

**MyItem.h**

```
#ifndef MYITEM_H
#define MYITEM_H

#include <QStandardItem>

class MyItem : public QStandardItem
{
public:
    explicit MyItem(const QString &text);
    ~MyItem();
};

#endif // MYITEM_H
```

**MyItem.cpp**

```
#include "MyItem.h"

MyItem::MyItem(const QString &text) :
    QStandardItem(text)
{

}

MyItem::~MyItem()
{
    qDebug("Gone");
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "MyItem.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QStandardItemModel model;
    auto *item = new MyItem("test");

    model.appendRow(item);
}
```

You could also experiment with:

```
auto *model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
model->appendRow(item);
model->deleteLater();
```

In either cases the application should output "Gone" immediately after it is run.

By the way, the result will be the same when using `model->removeRow(model->rowCount() - 1);` instead of `model->deleteLater();`.

As for the `QList<QStandardItem*> list;` in your code, `list` is a local variable. It is used as a container to pass the items to the model. After that it is not necessary and is destroyed when it goes out of scope. The items however will continue to exist either until removed from the model or the model gets destroyed.

Comment: Even when pointers are wrapped in a list and the list is added to model? The question arose because i found online that when using QList<*T> people had to deallocate objects with qDeleteAll().

Comment: While model exists? Or loop iteration?

Comment: thanks, that was the part that i wasn't clear with. so list is used as a carrier, once it is used by appendRow method, it gets thrown away because appendRow somehow picked up pointers and took ownership of them. from that point on, pointers are owned by the model, so deletion of child items works like you demonstrated (and is mentioned in documentation).

Comment: @mispp Exactly!

Comment: @mispp, just a remark, if you allow me. `list` is not thrown away by `appendRow`. It is destroyed when it goes out of scope. And not the pointers are owned by the model, but the objects. If you decide to keep a pointer and the object it is pointing to gets destroyed, the pointer will become dangling.